# Issues installing PHP amqp extension and librabbitMQ

Tags: centos, rabbitmq, amqp, amazon-ami

I am having some issues installing PHP amqp extension on a machine running Amazon Linux AMI.

I've managed to install librabbitmq-c (https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c) by downloading the latest tar and running those commands:

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
sudo cmake --build . [--config Release] --target install
```

Installation completed successfully.

Next, I tried to install php amqp by running

```
sudo pecl7 install amqp
```

but got an error saying that it could not find the rabbitmq files.

I executed it again and defined the path as `/usr/local/lib64/`, but this time got the following (pretty generic) error message:

```
configure: error: Please reinstall the librabbitmq distribution itself or (re)install librabbitmq development package if it available in your system
```

Anyone has any idea on to how get past this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those rpms solved the issue:

librabbitmq: https://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/7.6.1810/os/x86_64/Packages/librabbitmq-0.8.0-2.el7.x86_64.rpm

librabbitmq-devel: https://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/7.6.1810/os/x86_64/Packages/librabbitmq-devel-0.8.0-2.el7.x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 0):

Our OS was a centos and php version was 7.4
I ran
`yum install librabbitmq-devel -y`
before install `pecl install amqp` It worked for me